# MacBook Pro: Glitch/Copy of closed Window - Graphic card or monitor defect

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics

I have issues with my Mid 2012 MacBook Pro Retina 15.4" (16GB RAM, i7 2.6Ghz, 500GB Flash Drive, Dual Graphic: Intel + Nvidia GT 650M)

Whenever I open and close any of the application, it still stays on desktop for a few minutes - but with very low opacity (5% maybe - visible on pictures below). Is it some kind of glitch which is solvable or it maybe graphic card or screen is damaged?

I tried another macOS install, tried another Hard Disk, tried SMC Reset, Tried VRAM Reset. This is happening in macOS Sierra and macOS Catalina. After reboot it still stays over there for few minutes. I guess it is a screen/monitor defect?

[image]

[image]

[image]

What may be causing this? Is it possible to resolve it? And if yes, how?

Comment: Take a screen shot.  If the ghosting appears in the image, it’s your system.  If not, it’s your display panel meaning you need a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is display. It does not appears when i take screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook screen is experiencing what's called <strike>a burn in effect</strike> [image persistence](https://www.necdisplay.com/Documents/WhitePapers/Image_Persistence.pdf). This problem is an electric charge build up on the LCD. (Correction by [@Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382532/macbook-pro-glitch-copy-of-closed-window-graphic-card-or-monitor-defect/382533?noredirect=1#comment519921_382533))

It's a hardware issue and is generally resolved by screen replacement. There is no software fix for this issue.

<sub>(**P.S.**: Apparently, this issue was widely faced by a lot of Mid 2012 Retina MacBook Pro users. Related discussions [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4034848) and [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-retina-burn-in-problem.1606728/))</sub>

Comment: It's called [image persistence](https://www.necdisplay.com/Documents/WhitePapers/Image_Persistence.pdf), not burn in. Burn in occurs when the phosphor coating on the inside of the CRT is actually burnt with a residual image.  This problem is an electric charge build up on the LCD.

Comment: This laptop was dropped on the floor - it has display damage / crack on the corner. But still working. Do you think it may be because of that?  I guess it is not fixable?

Comment: @tbradaric It could likely be. I can not comment about whether it could be fixed.

Comment: It’s not from the drop.  See the link in the first comment